# Line polygon intersection in Bing maps

Tags: gis, geospatial, bing-maps

Disclaimer: I am not a GIS guy.

We are trying to use the DotSpatial library to calculate a line polygon intersection and then display that intersection in the WPF Bing Maps control.  For some reason any intersection that is not perfectly straight in the EW direction appears shifted down from the original line in Bing.  I'm assuming this is a projection problem as when we display everything in the DotSpatial control projected to WGS1984 the shifting does not occur.

To recreate put the following in the xaml code behind of the map window:

```
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using DotSpatial.Data;
using DotSpatial.Topology;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private LocationCollection _polygonLocs = new LocationCollection();

    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddSquarePolygon();

        // angled line 1
        LocationCollection slantedLocs = new LocationCollection();
        slantedLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(40, -97));
        slantedLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(35, -86));
        AddAndIntersectLine( slantedLocs );

        // straight EW line 
        LocationCollection ewLocs = new LocationCollection();
        ewLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(37, -97));
        ewLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(37, -86));
        AddAndIntersectLine(ewLocs);
    }

    private void AddAndIntersectLine(LocationCollection lineLocs)
    {
        MapPolyline line = new MapPolyline() { Locations = lineLocs, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) };

        this._bingMap.Children.Add(line);

        LocationCollection inters = Intersect(lineLocs, _polygonLocs);

        MapPolyline interLine = new MapPolyline() { Locations = inters, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) };
        this._bingMap.Children.Add(interLine);

    }

    private void AddSquarePolygon()
    {
        _polygonLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(39.0, -92));
        _polygonLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(36.0, -92));
        _polygonLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(36.0, -93));
        _polygonLocs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(39.0, -93));

        MapPolygon square = new MapPolygon()
        {
            Locations = _polygonLocs,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
        };

        this._bingMap.Children.Add(square);
    }

    public static LocationCollection Intersect(LocationCollection line, LocationCollection bounds)
    {
        Feature lineFeature = CreateFeatureFromLocations(line);
        Feature boundsFeature = CreateFeatureFromLocations(bounds);

        IFeature featureIntersection = boundsFeature.Intersection(lineFeature);

        if (featureIntersection != null)
        {
            return (CreateLocationsFromFeature(featureIntersection));
        }

        return new LocationCollection();
    }


    private static LocationCollection CreateLocationsFromFeature(IFeature feature)
    {
        LocationCollection lc = new LocationCollection();
        foreach (var coords in feature.Coordinates)
        {
            lc.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(coords.Y, coords.X));
        }

        return lc;
    }

    private static Feature CreateFeatureFromLocations(LocationCollection locs)
    {

        Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[locs.Count];
        long inx = 0;

        foreach (var l in locs)
        {
            Coordinate coord = new Coordinate();
            coord.X = l.Longitude;
            coord.Y = l.Latitude;
            coords[inx] = coord;
            inx++;
        }

        LineString ls = new LineString(coords);
        MultiLineString mls = new MultiLineString(ls);
        return new Feature(mls);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your line is a geodesic line (ie: a line on a geoid). And when plotted on a flat map, it should become an arc, and is not straight anymore.

1) You should add a function that cut the MapPolyline onto several segments to plot an arc close to reality

```
private static LocationCollection BuildGeodesicPolyline(Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location start, Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location end)
    {
        int segments = 32; // The number of line segments used to approximate the true curved route 
        LocationCollection latLongs = new LocationCollection();

        // Convert all coordinates to Radians
        double lat1 = start.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        double lon1 = start.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        double lat2 = end.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        double lon2 = end.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        // Calculate the total extent of the route
        double d = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((Math.Sin((lat1 - lat2) / 2)), 2) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Pow((Math.Sin((lon1 - lon2) / 2)), 2)));
        // Calculate the position at fixed intervals along the route
        for (double n = 0; n < segments + 1; n++)
        {
            double f = (1d / segments) * n;
            double A = Math.Sin((1 - f) * d) / Math.Sin(d);
            double B = Math.Sin(f * d) / Math.Sin(d);
            // Calculate 3D Cartesian coordinates of the point
            double x = A * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lon1) + B * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(lon2);
            double y = A * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Sin(lon1) + B * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Sin(lon2);
            double z = A * Math.Sin(lat1) + B * Math.Sin(lat2);
            // Convert these to latitude/longitude
            double lat = Math.Atan2(z, Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)));
            double lon = Math.Atan2(y, x);
            // Create a VELatLong representing this location (remember to convert back to degrees)
            double newLat = lat / (Math.PI / 180d);
            double newLon = lon / (Math.PI / 180d);
            Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location p = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(newLat, newLon);
            // Add this to the array
            latLongs.Add(p);
        }

        return latLongs;
    }
```

Taken from http://www.beginningspatial.com/plotting_geography_linestrings_google_maps_and_virtual_earth

If you add those lines after "angled line 1" block you will see the black dotted line that is in fact an arc :

```
slantedLocs = BuildGeodesicPolyline(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(35d, -86d),new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(40d, -97d)) ;
MapPolyline m = new MapPolyline() { Locations = slantedLocs, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), StrokeThickness = 2d, StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection(new List<double>() { 5, 5 }) };
_bingMap.Children.Add(m);
```

2) You should read about DotSpatial because the red line (result of intersection) is using flat-flane coordinate system and thus is wrong for your purposes. Here is what SQL Server says about this :

```
declare @p geography = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-92 39 , -93 39 , -93 36 ,-92 36  , -92 39 ))',4326)
declare @l1 geography = geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-97 40, -86 35)',4326)

declare @pG geometry = geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-92 39 , -93 39 , -93 36 ,-92 36  , -92 39 ))',4326)
declare @l1G geometry = geometry::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-97 40, -86 35)',4326)
select 
@p.STIntersection(@l1).ToString() as [GEODESIC] -- LINESTRING (-92.0000000179902 37.936656236067556, -93.000000053162651 38.376235391098518)
    , @pG.STIntersection(@l1G).ToString() as [PLANAR] -- LINESTRING (-93 38.18181818181818, -92 37.727272727272727)
```

The geometry operations between planar and geodesic geometries are differents at such scales.

Answer (score 0):

Your location collection / point of intersection test is not suited for *altitude*.

You are experiencing this because sometimes a point beside your polygon (on a spherical map) isn't necessarily outside of your polygon. We are trying to test 3D points on a 2D plain.

Just banged my head against the wall for a few days with this same issue! I came up with a visually appealing fix, which was quite simple.

Convert **all** your polygon lat / long to a `Point` object on the screen using `LocationToViewPortpoint` function, as well as the point you are testing for intersection, and use the X and Y values instead of your lat / long.